# What does "message to the main" mean?

Tags: meaning, british-english

I have been listening to the song *Written in the Stars* by Tinie Tempah and the lyrics go like this:

> Oh written in the stars
>   A million miles away
>   A **message to the main**
>   Oh
>   Seasons come and go
>   But I will never change
>   And I'm on my way

What does *message to the main* mean?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In context, the [Urban Dictionary](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=Message%20to%20the%20main) says the phrase means:

> Sending a message by something anyone can see.
>   *Written in the stars, a million miles away, a message to the main*

While another answer pointed out that [*main*](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/main) usually means the ocean or sea in literature, I don't think that it makes sense for the song. It is a rap song by Tinie Temptah, in which he seems to be talking about getting his name out. Thus, it makes more sense for *the main* to refer not to the sea but to the

> the chief or principal part or point.

He is "on his way" because his name is written in the stars for all to see.

Comment: Oh... This makes even more sense... You nailed the interpretation :)

Answer (score 2):

In literature and poetry, the word *main* means the ocean or sea.

Comment: +1 Ahh... very interesting! Now it makes sense... Thank You!

Answer (score 2):

According to the Oxford English Dictionary, the noun *main* (sometimes spelled *maine*) was also formerly used in poetry to mean "a broad expanse." This meaning makes more sense than *ocean* in this case, but I'm left wondering if this song really saying "a message to the main."

That's what the lyrics sites say, but those sites are full of mistakes. I just don't hear "to the main" in this song, and remember we are going back to the 1600s to find this definition. I think it sounds like "a message to the main goal."

This doesn't seem quite right either, but I suppose it could mean "a message about the main goal," since expressions like "speak to that" seem to be gaining favor vs. "speak about that." Listen closely and see what you think; it's a great song in any case!